# Prepend Macros to existing Template before processing

Tags: java, freemarker

- I have a `TemplateLoader` who's `getReader` will return a valid FTL, except the definition of macros used in the FTL are missing.
- All needed macro definitions will be passed by an external source as a `String`.
- For some complex reasons I am not allowed to change the `TemplateLoader` implementation or change the configuration object (meaning I will have to somehow incorporate the `String` in the result of `Configuration#getTemplate` itself).

I saw there is a `Template#addMacro` method, however it says it's used internally and expects a `Macro` (I have a `String` which defines multiple macros, parsing it myself doesn't seem the reasonable way to do it).

How can I prepend the macro definitions (or any valid FTL received as a `String` for that matter) before I call `Template#process`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that you can wrap the macros in a fictional template, create a processing environment (instead of directly processing the main template), include or import the fictional template in the processing environment and then process:

```
String macrosSource = getMacros();
// Needed to create the fictional template, has no real purpose
Configuration wrapper = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_21);
wrapper.setObjectWrapper(new DefaultObjectWrapperBuilder(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_21).build());

// Fictional template which has the only purpose to hold your macroSource
Template macrosFictionalTemplate = new Template(null, macroSource, wrapper);

// Get template as you normally would
Template mainTemplate = configuration.getTemplate("main_template");

// Create a processing environment. This is an object on which you can call
// .process just as you can on a template. The model and out are the same as
// Template#process(model, out)
Environment mainTemplateEnvironment = mainTemplate.createProcessingEnvironment(model, out);

// Either include -> macros will be accessible as top-level
mainTemplateEnvironment.include(macrosFictionalTemplate);
// Or import -> macros will be accessible using macros.macroName
mainTemplateEnvironment.importLib(macrosFictionalTemplate, "macros");

// Process everything
mainTemplateEnvironment.process();
```